# awk script to read txt file

Tags: csv, awk

How can I create the below output using awk? I couldn't create the loop for comma separated data.

`awk '{print "echo "$1"\nadd "$2"\nremove "$3"\nlist "$4}' test.txt`

**test.txt**

```
1 abc,bcd xyz,yza qwe,wer
2 abc xyz qwe
3 abc xyz,yza qwe,wer
4 abc,bcd xyz wer
```

**Output:**

```
echo 1
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 2
add abc
remove xyz
list qwe
echo 3
add abc
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 4
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
list wer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative approach is a two stage `awk`

```
$ awk '{ print "echo " $1; print "add " $2; print "remove " $3}' file 
  | awk -F'[ ,]' 'NF==3{print $1,$2; print $1,$3;next}1'
```

Comment: Thanks karakfa. Can you please explain second awk statement? It works for the example input but I am trying to modify this for my original input.

Comment: Well, it assumes that you'll either have 1 or 2 sub fields.  Second awk splits the fields by space and comma.  For 2 sub fields, NF will be 3, splits the rest on to two lines.  This will work for the sample set but for more sub fields might be harder to expand.  A looping solution might be better if that's your input.

Comment: here is one line from my input file: "abc bcd cde def:fed fed:abc,bcd" I need to split fed:abc,bcd on to two lines like: "abc bcd cde def:fed fed:abc" "abc bcd cde def:fed fed:bcd"

Comment: Darn, I upvoted the question because it seemed to be well written with concise sample input, output and an attempt at solving the problem and now a comment from the OP shows up with a major requirement that was completely absent from the question :-( !

Comment: I have more than one solution but I like @karakfa's approach, one line awk scripts. This also worked but I realized that I have ":".
I will open a new question. Thanks for your support all.

Answer (score 2):

I always feel like awk loses a bit of its pizazz when I have to do my own split and loop through the resulting array, but here is a straightforward way using a function to add the second loop in order to process your space-separated fields (that are themselves comma-separated values):

```
$ cat test.awk
function print_all(label, values) {
    split(values, v, ",")
    for (i=1; i<=length(v); ++i) {
        print label " " v[i]
    }
}

{
    print "echo " $1
    print_all("add", $2)
    print_all("remove", $3)
    print_all("list", $4)
}

$ cat test.txt
1 abc,bcd xyz,yza qwe,wer
2 abc xyz qwe
3 abc xyz,yza qwe,wer
4 abc,bcd xyz wer

$ awk -f test.awk test.txt
echo 1
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 2
add abc
remove xyz
list qwe
echo 3
add abc
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 4
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
list wer
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops, which is why you have a problem - you need to split your line on whitespace, but then split the subelements on commas.

I would suggest using `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @actions = qw ( echo add remove list ); 

#iterate the lines    
while ( <DATA> ) {
   #split on whitespace
   my @fields = split; 
   #iterate actions and fields
   foreach my $action ( @actions ) { 
      #split each field on ,
      #print action and field for each. 
      print "$action $_\n" for split ( ",", shift @fields ); 
   }
}

__DATA__
1 abc,bcd xyz,yza qwe,wer
2 abc xyz qwe
3 abc xyz,yza qwe,wer
4 abc,bcd xyz wer
```

This gives us:

```
echo 1
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 2
add abc
remove xyz
list qwe
echo 3
add abc
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 4
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
list wer
```

Which I think is what you wanted?

This can be reduced to a one liner:

```
perl -ane 'for my $act ( qw ( echo add remove list ) ) { print "$act $_\n" for split ",", shift @F }' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily recommended but if you're looking for compact you could replace commas with the extra text including the line breaks.

```
a = "," $2; b = "," $3; c = "," $4;
gsub(/,/, "\nadd ", a);
gsub(/,/, "\nremove ", b);
gsub(/,/, "\nlist ", c);
print "echo " $1 a b c "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { split("echo add remove list",names) }
{
    for (fldNr=1;fldNr<=NF;fldNr++) {
        split($fldNr,subFlds,/,/)
        for (subFldNr=1;subFldNr in subFlds; subFldNr++) {
            print names[fldNr], subFlds[subFldNr]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
echo 1
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 2
add abc
remove xyz
list qwe
echo 3
add abc
remove xyz
remove yza
list qwe
list wer
echo 4
add abc
add bcd
remove xyz
list wer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F" " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){a[i]=$i;} {print "echo "a[1]"\n""add "a[2]"\nremove "a[3]"\nlist "a[4];}}' filename | awk -F" " '{sub(/,/,"\n"$1" ",$0);print}'
```

The above code can be used.
Also I would like to get inputs from others for an optimized code snippet of the above version.